# add "Where" to a linq statement?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, signalr, where-clause

I don't know linq AT ALL.  The guy that does all our backend work is out for 2 weeks, but all I need to do is filter **getItemList** based on "term".  I've tried searching for how to add a "where" clause but I'm simply having no luck.

Note that I added "string term" to the **getItemList** parameters.

Please help.

```
public IndexedItem getItem(string name) {
    var repo = new Project.SQLServerDataManager.IndexItemRepository(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ItemRepositoryConnstring"].ConnectionString);
    return repo.getItem(name);
}

public object getItemList(string term) {
    var repo = getRepo();
    return from i in repo.getItem() 
        select new { name = i.name, itemType = i.itemType.name };
}

private IIndexedItemReadOnlyRepository getRepo() { 
    return new Project.SQLServerDataManager.IndexItemRepository(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ItemRepositoryConnstring"].ConnectionString);
}
```

**Edit to clarify:** "term" is the search term.  It needs to match the item "name"

Comment: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b is a very good place to look if you want simple examples on a variety of LINQ queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public object getItemList(string term) {
    var repo = getRepo();
    return from i in repo.getItem() 
           where i.Name == term
           select new { name = i.name, itemType = i.itemType.name };
}
```

Comment: changed where to "where i.name.Contains(term)" and it works great.  Thanks!

Comment: @ScottBeeson You should take a look at the link SamiHuutoniemi posted if you want a quick reference samples on how to work with linq.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 public object getItemList(string term) {
    var repo = getRepo();
    return from i in repo.getItem() 
           where i.Term = "Your Term"
           select new { name = i.name, itemType = i.itemType.name };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's two good starter links on LINQ for your coworker's future vacations, too:

[Introduction to LINQ Queries (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397906.aspx)

[A Primer on LINQ and Lambda](http://codefoster.com/post/2012/05/01/A-Primer-on-LINQ-and-Lambda)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with "where" two ways:

Adding it into your code:

```
return from i in repo.getItem() 
       where i.Name == "Test Value"
       select new { name = i.name, itemType = i.itemType.name };
```

Or:

```
return repo.getItem().Where(item => item.Name == "Test Value").Select(item => new { name = i.name, itemType = i.itemType.name });
```

I don't know where I found it but I have this bookmarked for LINQ reference, it explains the basics of LINQ and how to use the functions: http://www.dotnetperls.com/linq